# Reducing on Results obtained by jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code I used looks something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = $('#exam-percent-weightage > td > input').not('[type=hidden]').not('[disabled=disabled]').get().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return specialParseFloat(a === undefined ? 0 : a.value) + specialParseFloat(b === undefined ? 0 : b.value);
  });
  console.log(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr id="exam-percent-weightage">
  <td class="weightagePadding"> <strong>First Term</strong> 
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="data[Exam][0][percent_weightage]" class="form-control percentWeight" value="0.00" step="any" id="Exam0PercentWeightage" type="number">
    <input name="data[Exam][0][id]" class="testId" value="30" id="Exam0Id" type="hidden">
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;%</td>
  <td class="buttonPadding">+</td>
  <td class="weightagePadding"> <strong>Second Term</strong> 
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="data[Exam][1][percent_weightage]" class="form-control percentWeight" value="0.00" step="any" id="Exam1PercentWeightage" type="number">
    <input name="data[Exam][1][id]" class="testId" value="31" id="Exam1Id" type="hidden">
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;%</td>
  <td class="buttonPadding">+</td>
  <td class="weightagePadding"> <strong>Third Term</strong> 
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="data[Exam][2][percent_weightage]" class="form-control percentWeight" value="0.00" step="any" id="Exam2PercentWeightage" type="number">
    <input name="data[Exam][2][id]" class="testId" value="32" id="Exam2Id" type="hidden">
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;%</td>
  <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>=</strong> 
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="total-weight" type="number">
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;%</td>
  <td class="buttonPadding">
    <button type="submit" class="action-mainbtn">Save</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Note: The jQuery version I have to use is actually 1.12.1  (which was not available in SO snippet tool)

FYI: I've defined specialParseFloat and the error is probably not related to that. Anyway the function is as follows:

```
function specialParseFloat(something) {
    return parseFloat(something) || 0;
}
```

The behavior I am getting in my browser (FF) is that reduce only returns the last value instead of adding all the values in the input box. This however works correctly with the case of having only two inputs.

What did I do incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Bastien Mercier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7049095/bastien-mercier) , I re-read the documentation. I did two things incorrectly.

First, I assumed that the params to `reduce` were `(firstValue, secondValue)` (so silly of me) which instead should have been `(accumulator, currentValue)`

Second, I did not pass the initialValue, which according to docs, results in index being started from 1.

The corrections now, would be to change `a === undefined ? 0 : a.value` to `a === undefined ? 0 : a` or just `a` (since we pass inital value) and to pass initial value of 0 to enforce `reduce` to start from 0th position in array.

Answer (score 3):

according to the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) you have to set an accumulator as third param of reduce, and use it to add your value. Because you don't use accumulator, your last evaluation will be the final result.

Comment: As far as I understand, I'm passing two arguments to `reduce` , `a` being the accumulator and `b` being the current value. each time I return from reduce, the value will be assigned to accumulator and on each call to reduce I will be adding the value of accumulator to currentvalue. the `a === undefined ? 0 : a.value` kind of mimics the usage of initalValue. Could you please explain further?

Comment: Okay, just got the flaw. `a.value` , I'll check and edit the question.